# close child aspx page if gridview index is changed on parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a parent page and child page, both aspx. All is working, but now I would like to close child page, if user leaves child popup page and goes back to parent page and clicks on something else like page index of Gridview. I CANNOT close popup child page if user goes to another app, or some other location, I only want to close if something on parent page is changed.

I have the PageIndexChange Event set up for other purposes, I would just like to add some functionality, perhaps a script manager to close the child popup page if the Gridview index is changed, java or another way which ever works best.

I think I might also need to check if the child page is even open.

Any help and examples would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED: This is the code that opens the popup child page...

```
' Sets up popup to open when row selected for edit is cycled in DataRowBound event
    If IsPostBack Then
        If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
            If Session("updateComplete") <> "Y" And Session("CancelUpdate") <> "Y" Then
                Dim BrowserSettings As String = "status=no,toolbar=no, scrollbars =yes,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no," & "titlebar=no, addressbar=no, width=650, height=800"
                Dim URL As String = "pttStringPopUp.aspx"
                Dim scriptText1 As String = ("<script>javascript: var w = window.open('" & URL & "','_blank','" & BrowserSettings & "'); </script>")

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "ClientScript1", scriptText1, False)
                Session("updateComplete") = "N"
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an `onclick` handler in the `RowDataBound` event, and in the event close the popup:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("rowClick({0});", e.Row.RowIndex); 
}
```

ASPX:

```
var dialog;
var selectedRowIndex;

rowClick = function(rowIndex){
    if (selectedRowIndex){
        if (rowIndex != selectedRowIndex){ 
            selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
            if (dialog){
                dialog.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work because the user must be allowed to leave the child page. I can only close the child if the gridview page index changes. RowDataBound would not give me reason to close child page unless I could check if page index had changed. Not sure how to do that or how to close child page from parent page.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my answer. I'm just attaching a click event to the `GridViewRow` in the `RowDataBound` event. Your closing the child window when a row is clicked and the JavaScript function is fired.

Comment: I think I would need to close the child window then as well, that is if the row selected changed, from the row that caused the popup. Hmm, Im lost on this one.

Comment: When a row is selected, does it trigger a postback?

Comment: Trust me - this is where you need to start. It's just a matter of ironing out the details now.

Comment: No it causes a the popup to open and populates it with data from one of the gridview row cells for editing. Long story, but has to be this way, text blob, parsed on CRLF in popup. Anyway, it gets translated and sent back to Parent page, reassembled, unless something changes on parent while popup is open.

Comment: How is the popup being opened? JavaScript?

Comment: @marc11h: Updated my answer. I think that should get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: We just need to make sure that it doesn't conflict with the logic that opens the child window. How is the child window being opened? Is there a button to open it or something?

Comment: Its not working, I get a debug error, the line e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = String.Format("checkDialog({0});", e.Row.RowIndex); fires but does nothing. How does dialog get the popup page name?  Editing submission with more code...

Comment: Assign `dialog` to the window object when you open it.

Comment: Im guessing this is to be done in the Script Manager in VB. Its still not working. If I click on the Edit link of another row it simply opens another popup child page.

Comment: No... edit your question and include the code you're using to open the window when a user clicks on a row.

Comment: I did, it is posted near the bottom of my original post. Its the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript